# Problems with soap php call because of xml error

Tags: php, xml, soap, webserver

i'm trying to make a soap call to a web service to pass shipping data. Here is the request i'm sending so far:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://weblabeling.gls-italy.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:AddParcel env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <!-- bof shipping array --->
            <XMLInfoParcel>
                <Info>
                    <SedeGls>XXXX</SedeGls>
                    <CodiceClienteGls>XXXXX</CodiceClienteGls>
                    <PasswordClienteGls>XXXXXX</PasswordClienteGls>
                    <Parcel>
                        <CodiceContrattoGls>XXXXXX</CodiceContrattoGls>
                        <RagioneSociale>XXXXXX</RagioneSociale>
                        <!-- other stuff here -->
                    </Parcel>
                </Info>
            </XMLInfoParcel>
            <!-- eof shipping array --->
        </ns1:AddParcel>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

this is instead what webservice is asking me

```
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <AddParcel xmlns="http://weblabeling.gls-italy.com/">
          <XMLInfoParcel>string</XMLInfoParcel>
        </AddParcel>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

I always get as response xml format error.

What is wrong?
Shipping array is correct and match perfectly the request one.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:

Here is how i build xml:

```
//inseriamo i dati nei corretti array
$Label = array(
                'XMLInfoParcel' => array(
                'Info' => array(
                    'SedeGls' => $SedeGls,
                    'CodiceClienteGls' => $CodiceClienteGls,
                    'PasswordClienteGls' => $PasswordClienteGls,                
                    'Parcel' => array(
                                       'CodiceContrattoGls' => $cod_cont,
                                       'RagioneSociale' => $rag_soc,
                                       'Indirizzo' => $delivery_indirizzo,
                                       'Localita' => $delivery_city,
                                       'Zipcode' => $data['delivery_postcode'],
                                       'Provincia' => $data['zone_code'],
                                       'Bda' => '',
                                       'DataDocumentoTrasporto' => '',
                                       'Colli' => '1',
                                       'Incoterm' => '',
                                       'PesoReale' => '1,00',
                                       'ImportoContrassegno' => $imp_cont,
                                       'NoteSpedizione' => $data['customers_telephone'],
                                       'TipoPorto' => 'F',
                                       'Assicurazione' => $ass_ins,
                                       'PesoVolume' => '',
                                       'TipoCollo' => $tipo_collo,
                                       'FrancoAnticipata' => '',
                                       'RiferimentoCliente' => '',
                                       'NoteAggiuntive' => '',
                                       'CodiceClienteDestinatario' => '',
                                       'Email' => '',
                                       'Cellulare1' => $telefono_1,
                                       'Cellulare2' => '',
                                       'ServiziAccessori' => '',
                                       'ModalitaIncasso' => $mod_inc    
                                      ),),),                                
                );


$dom = new DOMDocumentExt('1.0', 'utf-8');              
$chiamta = $dom->loadArray($Label);
$dudy = $dom->saveXML();
```

@Iserni i put ---> only here, this is not in my code, i'm going to Test the online tool, i really don't see errors.

I still get error of xml format, any other clue guys?

Edited:

I just noticed my request has:

```
<ns1:AddParcel env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
```

while the required is:

```
<AddParcel xmlns="http://weblabeling.gls-italy.com/">
```

So i noticed also in envelope there is something different with namespaces. 
Could it be the problem?

WSDL seems to not work on gls server, they did not provide any info in documentation about it.

Edited:

Maybe i'm dumb but this is the request xml schema:

[image: schema]

So now shall i place more whitespace before ?
What do you think? and if so how?

Comment: I think you should add the relevant code how you create the Soap Request XML.

Comment: php is a nightmare with soap.... i'd suggest you to adapt the nusoap library to your proyect, and see how it makes the xml to perform it

Comment: Ah no, php Soap is pretty much okay. Also if you look in the question you can see that Fabio is pretty close already.

Comment: @Fabio: Everything but `<XMLInfoParcel>` element look good. If you add the code how you create the request, especially adding that one is useful for your question.

Comment: yes i think i'm pretty close. I actually do generate xml with a class, data are stored in  db. i'm gonna add a part of the script

Comment: Yes, a part is enough, the interesting part is where you create the SOAP request.

Comment: Wow, you are adding toooo much I'd say. Are you following some guideline or why do you do that?

Comment: @harke this is my first time i use soap, i have had already built xml because i thought i could be able to send directly, when i started with soap client i just used xml i already had. How do you think ishould do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have three errors in your XML, but you can easily find them (and future ones) using `xmllint` (also [online](http://www.awthomson.com/tools/xmllint.html)).

Basically, your XML comments ought to end with `-->` and not `--->`, and you should check tag opening/closing.

Also, the request is for `<XMLInfoParcel>string</XMLInfoParcel>`, but that is not what you're sending...?

Comment: I thought those comments have been added in the question to make visible about which part OP is concerned. But maybe you're right.

Comment: I too had this doubt; same goes for the 'string', I expected a different error from "XML Format Error". Unless the GLS code rejects any error at all as "XML format error".

Comment: I smell the typical problem how to setup the value for the parameter. It should be a string, but here in the request is a complex type. That can happen if an array is put in when creating a kind of `SoapVar`.

Comment: @Iserni: <XMLInfoParcel>string</XMLInfoParcel> actually i didn't no include all the request structure anyway i just added array in my question, you can see from there what it requires.

Comment: Why don't you use the standard way to create a correct request? Why do you make use of that `$gls->buildXMLRequest()`? Is there a specific reason you don't use the WSDL and let `SoapClient` do the work for you?

Comment: Also if you want to build the XML, use a `DomDocument` for that, it will always create valid XML.

Comment: @hakre There is no specific reason, i just used te same way to build xml ad i used with ebay api. I can use different methods, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Fabio: Take a look if there is a WSDL. If there is, use SoapClient with the WSDL. You then don't need to build the XML. If not, convert your XML creator making use of [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument). That should prevent you from doing some mistakes creating the XML unnoticed. But I think there even is something like `SoapVar` that turns an array into XML. I would check for that, too.

Comment: @hankre: i used dom i'm gonna change the way i build xml up here. Anyway it stills give me error xml format